# How to remove the padding between preference title and the following preference?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, androiddesignsupport, preferencescreen

I would like to remove the purple gap in my preference screen:
[preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEbJX.png)

so that it should look like this:
[Google Play Store example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grWOs.png)

I'm using Xamarin Android and c# to develop my app.
The preference screen is an PreferenceFragmentCompat from Android.Support.V7.Preferences library. The material style is set in my custom theme:

```
<style name="Theme.DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">#039be5</item><!--#FF4081-->
   <item name="colorControlHighlight">#242424</item>
   <item name="android:listDivider">@style/android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dim_dark</item> 
   <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

Here is how my xml resource file looks like, which I call by AddPreferencesFromResource(Resources.Id.preference_screen) in my PreferenceFragmentCompats OnCreatePreferences() function:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    android:title="App">
        <Preference
            android:key="advsettings_preference"
            android:title="Erweiterte Einstellungen" />
        <Preference
            android:key="license_preference"
            android:title="Rechtliche Hinweise" />
   </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

I already tried to fix it myself by adding padding attributes to PreferenceScreen, but nothing changed.

All the latest NuGet Packages from Xamarin Android are installed (v27.0.2).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide your custom theme `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material`?

Comment: The Android.Support.V7.Preferences library provides `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material`. I'm just referring to it. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c) on how to develop your own preference screen. He ends up in the same result, but there must be a way to remove the margin/padding. Else Google Play Store or Whats App, which are based on the same theme, wouldn't look like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try set the style like this;

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/MyPreferenceStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPreferenceStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/MyPreferenceCategoryStyle</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPreferenceCategoryStyle" parent="@style/Preference.Category.Material">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/preference_category</item>
</style>
```

And `preference_category.axml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And AppSettings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="App">
        <Preference
            android:key="advsettings_preference"
            android:title="Erweiterte Einstellungen"
            android:summary="BenachRichtigung"/>
    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

It will resolve the gap issue. And also look similar to your screenshot of Google Play Store. Well, not exactly the same from the Layout Inspector, but similar:

[image]

Comment: The purple gap problem is now fixed, but I want to add the padding left/right. I followed your steps, but the result looks like [that](https://i.imgur.com/mDxHk8i.jpg) and now I have like 3x 8dp peddings. How do I get only  the outermost pedding (1) ?

Comment: These frames and gaps are automatically generated by `PreferenceCategory` and containers inside. You can see that from Layout Inspector. I don't think it's possible to remove them. please consider change to use other type of preference instead.

Answer (score 0):

The purple area when looking at your layout with "use layout bounds" in the developer options enabled represent margins, not padding as far as I know.

I suggest trying to make a custom layout for your `PreferenceCategory` and your `Preference`'s and setting them in your above axml using the `android:layout` attribute as such:

```
android:layout="@layout/layout_name"
```

(Might need to play around with both [android:layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:layout) and [android:widgetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:widgetLayout) attributes)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"` to `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory` or any other element in my preference_screen.xml doesn't help.

Comment: @pedzer Updated my answer, have a look please.

Comment: I already tried to make my own custom layout, but didn't manage to get resources of PreferenceCatogory in `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material` to make it look like the Google Play Store. Nevertheless, I will check it a second time later this week.